# Url routemap rewriting mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following route and it works fine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Books",
"books/{id}/{bookName}",
new { controller = "books", action = "Book", bookName = "" }, new { id = @"^\d+$" } 
);
```

`http://localhost/books/1/cook-book` takes us to the books Controller and the book Action.

I have another Action in the books Controller, named bookInfo.

My question is how do I make the bookInfo action have the same url as the Book action?

Comment: what's the difference between the "Book" action and the "bookInfo" action?

Comment: bookInfo is a different Action that give detail information on the book.

Comment: Probably you are looking for an ajax request.